# How to add second close function to button?

Tags: javascript, api, button

Here I am using an API to open a livechat thing, I would like it so when they click it again, it closes it. The function for closing it is LC_API.close_chat_window();

Current code:

```
<li><a onclick="LC_API.open_chat_window();" href="javascript:void(0);"> CONTACT</a></li>
```

Comment: Right now you don't have any easy way to select your anchor tag, if you did you could just do something like this: `document.getElementById("id").attribute("onclick","LC_API.close_chat_window();");` after your open even ran.

Comment: If your API doesn't already have some way to test whether a chat is currently open then add one, and then: `onclick="LC_API.is_chat_window_open ? LC_API.close_chat_window() : LC_API.open_chat_window();"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function openCloseChat() {
        if (LC_API.agents_are_available()) {
            if (LC_API.chat_window_minimized()) {
                LC_API.open_chat_window();
            } else {
                LC_API.minimize_chat_window();
            }
        } else {
            alert('No agent available.');
        }
    }
```